# Only Tomcat WAR deployment using Jenkins

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins

Only Tomcat WAR deployment using Jenkins:

Here is the scinario for deployment:

- 3 Environment Production, pre-Production and Qualification
- 2 War files like app1 and app2
- 2 Tomcat servers Like Server1 and Server2 for each Environment (Point 1)

War files scinario:

- Developer gives war files like app1##20171122.war and app2##20171122.war
- app1 and app2 settings files are not part of war.
- Settings files are different for each Environment (Production, pre-Production and Qualification)
- After deployment of app1 and app2 we put the settings files at webapps/app1##20171122/config/Application.settings and webapps/app2##20171122/config/Application.settings
- Finally app1 and app2 starts using tomcat manager

  **Here is what I want to do with Jenkins:**

  Using Mavin deployment or any other tool:

  **Note:** Here War files size is more than 450MB

  **Jenkin Project App1:**

  1. We will put the app1##20171122.war files on Jenkins server
  2. We should be able to auto select the war file for deployment along with war version
  3. We should be able to deploy war files on multiple servers (Server1 and Server2)
  4. Deploy the setting files for app1 under webapps/app1##20171122/config/Application.settings
  5. Start the app1

**Note:** Application is not yet ready to read configuration from outside of webapps

**In short:**
(**Jenkins Server:** App1 war files & their setting files) ==(deploy on remote VM)==>(Tomcat server)

(**Jenkins Server:** Auto select App1 war) ==(deploy on remote VM)==>(Tomcat server)

(**Jenkins Server:** App1 Setting file ) ==(deploy setting on remote VM)==>(Tomcat server)

(**Jenkins Server:** Start App1 command ) ==(Send Command to remote VM)==>(Tomcat server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created following things to solve this:

Maven:

1. Installed Maven and created following pom.xml
2. Created one small shell script to unzip war, put the setting file related to specific environment and again created war file

Jenkins:

1. Used the Jenkins **Filesystem List Parameter Plug-in** with "This project is parameterized" option.
2. Used "Invoke top level Maven targets" from Build Option and used the following maven command
3. Please use following "WAR-NAME" while configuring File system parameter

   deploy -Papp1 -Papp2 -DwarFile=${WAR-NAME}

Pom.xml:

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.app1.app</groupId>
<artifactId>app1</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>my-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <warFile>none</warFile>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>app1</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>regex-property</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>regex-property</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <name>warFilename</name>
                                <value>${warFile}</value>
                                <regex>.war$</regex>
                                <replacement></replacement>
                                <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id> unzip, put setting file and zip again </id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <commandlineArgs>${warFile}</commandlineArgs>
                        <executable>${basedir}/make_war.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy-app1-1</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy-only</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <username>admin</username>
                                <password>adminpass</password>
                                <warFile>${basedir}/deploy/${warFile}</warFile>
                                <url>http://localhost:9090/manager/text</url>
                                <server>Tomcat</server>
                                <path>/app1</path>
                                <update>true</update>
                                <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>app2</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy-app1-2</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy-only</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <username>admin</username>
                                <password>adminpass</password>
                                <warFile>${basedir}/deploy/${warFile}</warFile>
                                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                                <server>Tomcat</server>
                                <path>/app1</path>
                                <update>true</update>
                                <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

make_war.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: not enough arguments. Please pass the WAR file name !!!"
  exit 2
elif [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: too many arguments. Please only pass the WAR file name !!!"
  exit 2
fi

war_file_name=$1
file_name=$(basename "$war_file_name")
extension="${war_file_name##*.}"
file_name="${file_name%.*}"

if [ $extension != "war" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: Invalid arguments. Please pass valid WAR file with version name !!!"
  exit 2
fi

echo "Cleaning up the deploy folder ..."
/usr/bin/rm -rf ./deploy/*
/usr/bin/unzip $war_file_name -d ./deploy/$file_name
/usr/bin/cp -f Application.settings ./deploy/$file_name/config/Application.settings
/usr/local/java/latest/bin/jar -cvf ./deploy/$war_file_name -C ./deploy/$file_name .
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to get Jenkins to deploy your applications and their configuration to your Tomcat instances?

I think using the Maven `deploy` plugin might be your best bet to physically deploy the files.

What I've done when I needed to deploy multiple copies/versions of an application to multiple Tomcat servers is to create a new directory `wars` to contain the .war files, and use Tomcat 
[Context Containers](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) to configure the individual application instances. Like this:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/app1.xml
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/app2.xml
$CATALINA_HOME/wars/app1-1.0.0.war
$CATALINA_HOME/wars/app1-1.0.1.war
$CATALINA_HOME/wars/app2-1.0.1.war
```

When you deploy a .war file to `../webapps`, Tomcat treats each .war as a separate application. I presume you can provide additional configuration for these apps, but I don't recall how.

But, if you use Context Container files, multiple application instances can use the same .war file. You can keep multiple revisions of the .war file on hand in case you need to roll back to an earlier version, or want to keep running an old version.

Comment: I have added more info in last part (In Short)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do :

- Configure "target" servers through ssh in jenkins.
- Take parameters as input; what target, what .war, what .settings file etc
- Copy .war and .settings file to target server over SCP/SSH through jenkins along with a script which does the following.
- Explode .war (do unzip)
- Copy required .settings files inside exploded war
- Start tomcat

I had built .war using Jenkins as a build job and a downstream job was used for deployment on a tomcat based environment whose details were picked up as a build parameter.

> Developer gives war files like app1##20171122.war and app2##20171122.war

You haven't mentioned how developer "gives" you these war files. If they are "built", I suggest create a job to build these war using ant/maven etc so that locations where these wars reside is already known.
If they are to be provided, you can upload them to any centralized location (FTP server) or over some artifactory such as JFrog/Nexu and download directly on tomcat server.